# JGit: What does TreeWalk's setFilter do Exactly?

Tags: jgit

In JGit, my understanding is that `TreeWalk` object is a list of trees from the repository provided in the constructor. If I have a TreeWalk `TreeWalk walker = new TreeWalk(repository)` and then do:

```
TreeWalk walker = new TreeWalk(repository);
walker.setFilter(PathFilter.create("/src/TargetFile.txt");
```

Then every RevTree I add will only contain the file TargetFile.txt?

Answer (score 0):

You use a `RevWalk` to identify a specific tree of files in a git repository.

Then you can use a `TreeWalk` to iterate over files/directories from the single  commit.

You can use filters which select multiple files as well, e.g. the following selects `*.txt`

```
    treeWalk.setFilter(PathSuffixFilter.create(".txt"));
```

The [JavaDoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/5.13.0.202109080827-r/org/eclipse/jgit/treewalk/TreeWalk.html#setFilter-org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.filter.TreeFilter-) explains how `setFilter()` works and how you can combine multiple filters.

There is a ready-to-run [snippet](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/4b68d561c88904100cc8adb747dd6d0b58627969/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/api/GetFileAttributes.java#L71) in the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) which shows how to use `RevWalkt` and `TreeWalk`